# How to check if the date has valid format in Yup?

Tags: javascript, validation, yup, react-final-form

I am using yup to validate the values in the input field:

```
const dateToCheck = yup
    .date()
    .nullable()
    .transform((curr, orig) => (orig === '' ? null : curr))
    .required()
    .min(minDate, 'Date cannot be this early')
    .max(maxDate, 'Date too much in the future')
    .test('format', 'Date is invalid', date => (date?.getFullYear() ?? 0) <= 9999)
```

I have been trying to figure out how to check if the input date has the correct format?
Because of how yup works, both `01.01.2000` and `2000/01/01` will pass `date` validation but I would like to be able to only `dd.MM.yyyy` format to pass or only `yyyy/MM/dd` format to pass not both and then every other format which would be valid otherwise be labelled as invalid instead. What is the correct way to do it in yup?

Comment: Maybe use regex and .matches() method?

Comment: @protob should I use it in .test method?

Comment: .matches() is a separate method in yup, but you can also write regex in test method callback

Comment: @protob `.matches()` method wont work when you are checking if the value is a `.date()` like I am doing above

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach to showing an error when the format is incorrect, you can change the input date to the format you want. Following example will parse all dates to `yyyy-MM-dd` format:

```
import { parse, isDate } from "date-fns";

function parseDateString(value, originalValue) {
  const parsedDate = isDate(originalValue)
    ? originalValue
    : parse(originalValue, "yyyy-MM-dd", new Date());

  return parsedDate;
}
```

Source: https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/Yup-Date-Validation-with-Custom-Transform

Comment: May mention that you've just copied code in your answer from here: https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/Yup-Date-Validation-with-Custom-Transform

Answer (score -1):

**You can add these regular expression validations to your existing Yup schema by chaining the .matches() method after the .test()**

```
const dateToCheck = yup
.date()
.nullable()
.transform((curr, orig) => (orig === '' ? null : curr))
.required()
.min(minDate, 'Date cannot be this early')
.max(maxDate, 'Date too much in the future')
.test('format', 'Date is invalid', date => (date?.getFullYear() ?? 0) <= 9999)
.matches(/^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})$/, 'Date must be in format dd.MM.yyyy');
```